# How to not move images around and push elements when browser is resizing

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML and CSS code. If you run this, there will be a image of a macbook and a 'buy' button. When the browser is minimised, the image is alittle off from the center. When it is in full screen, it causes the image to move up and the 'buy' button gets pushed to the bottom. I tried to use position: fixed but it didnt work. How do you make the picture have fixed position in the middle

```css
.new {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: rgb(202, 137, 15);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.macbook {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 44px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.supercharged {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.price {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #007aff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.charged {
  color: plum;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.picture {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html align='center'>

<body>
  <p class='new'>New</p>
  <h2 class='macbook'>MacBook Pro</h3>
    <h1 class='supercharged'><span class='charged'>Supercharged</span> for pros.</h1>
    <p class='price'>From $1999</p>
    <a href="/text.html"><button class='button'>Buy</button></a>
    <img src="https://images.macrumors.com/t/PV_LL2AlRJvaRvbuXCTUOuDpwzU=/800x0/smart/article-new/2013/09/16-inch-macbook-pro.jpg?lossy" alt="Macbook" class='picture'>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Both your `<img>` and your `<a>` are displaying `inline` (or `inline-block`). The only time they appear stacked vertically is when the screen isn't wide enough for them to sit side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `display: block` to the `<a>`-element. When you use `display: block` on an element, it will try to take up as much width as possible. Seeing as it is not inside a parent container, it will take up 100% width of the `<body>`-element, as that is the elements closest parent. This way, it won't wrap around the image. The link will however stretch and fill the entire parent container as well. To combat this, apply `max-width: fit-content`, so the link's width is only relative to its content. Then you can apply `margin: auto` to center the element again.

For a responsive image, apply `max-width: 100%` and `height: auto`. This way it will automatically scale down, as the `max-width: 100%` property won't let it overflow its parent container (the `<body>`-element)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.new {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: rgb(202, 137, 15);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.macbook {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 44px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.supercharged {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.price {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #007aff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.charged {
  color: plum;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.picture {
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  display: block;
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class='new'>New</p>
<h2 class='macbook'>MacBook Pro</h3>
  <h1 class='supercharged'><span class='charged'>Supercharged</span> for pros.</h1>
  <p class='price'>From $1999</p>
  <a href="/text.html"><button class='button'>Buy</button></a>
  <img src="https://images.macrumors.com/t/PV_LL2AlRJvaRvbuXCTUOuDpwzU=/800x0/smart/article-new/2013/09/16-inch-macbook-pro.jpg?lossy" alt="Macbook" class='picture'>
```

Comment: It worked tyy :D

Answer (score 0):

By default an image is displayed `inline`, which is causing your issue. You're on the right track, but instead of position fixed, `position: block;` would be a better choice.

(You can also centre your image and avoid it overflowing using a `max-width` and some `margin`)

```css
.new {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: rgb(202, 137, 15);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.macbook {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 44px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.supercharged {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.price {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #007aff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.charged {
  color: plum;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.picture {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html align='center'>

<body>
  <p class='new'>New</p>
  <h2 class='macbook'>MacBook Pro</h3>
    <h1 class='supercharged'><span class='charged'>Supercharged</span> for pros.</h1>
    <p class='price'>From $1999</p>
    <a href="/text.html"><button class='button'>Buy</button></a>
    <img src="https://images.macrumors.com/t/PV_LL2AlRJvaRvbuXCTUOuDpwzU=/800x0/smart/article-new/2013/09/16-inch-macbook-pro.jpg?lossy" alt="Macbook" class='picture'>
</body>

</html>
```